# Replace element text using contains() selector and replace()

Tags: jquery, html, contains

I have few lists with language options:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">English (English)</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Polski (Polish)</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to change each `English (English)` to `EN`, but with no results

```
$('a:contains("English (English)")').html().replace('English (English)', 'EN');
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating element text, just updating the returned string. Use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)** with a function to update based on the old html content.

```js
$('a:contains("English (English)")').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace('English (English)', 'EN');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">English (English)</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Polski (Polish)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".dropdown-menu").find('li a').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'English (English)';
}).text('EN');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">English (English)</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Polski (Polish)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

use `.filter()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use replaceWith() to replace content of any div:

```
$('a:contains("English (English)")').replaceWith('<a href="#">EN</a>');
```